# How to view selenium tests running on a jenkins slave running on a windows 7 server?

Tags: windows, selenium, jenkins, master-slave

We have a build environment set up with Jenkins running on a linux server. In order to run some integration tests on a windows specific project, we have a Windows 7 server vm set up as a hudson slave. This set up is all working correctly.

These integration tests consist of a set of selenium tests, in order to diagnose failures it would be useful to witness the tests running.

When connecting to the server via RDC, using the same username the master is running the slave under I don't see the tests running, and the Jenkins slave and the Firefox instance aren't showing on the task manager. Selecting view all processes I can see the slave process and the firefox process running under the username I'm connected as, and firefox is running with a -foreground flag.

I can only conclude I've connected as a separate concurrent connection on the same account, is there a way to connect to the same session the hudson slave is running under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried the following to check the running tests

- Log on using VMWare vsphere client and open console of the VM machine
- We tried recording the entire desktop session as long as the tests run and also artifact the recorded session along with the jenkins build. We have used VLC recorder which can be started from command prompt(from jenkins) just before the tests start and save them after the tests finish executing. The saved recording file is added to the build artifacts.

These are better ways than to interfere with the original connection because that may disrupt the running of the current session.

Answer (score 0):

Set up Jenkins
Set up AllurePlugin on Jenkins
Set up Allure report on Your test ( it is really simple )

If everything goes as planned you will have access to report directly from jenkins.